# Couldn't retrieve value from Parent Object as an element in a List

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am working on a Test Class in which i have created Lists for each sObject and assigning ParentIds to the Parent objects while creating a Child record like this:

```
List<Parent_Object1__c> ParentList1 = new List<Parent_Object1__c>();
ParentList1.add(new Parent_Object1__c(Parent1_Field__c = 'RandomParentValue'));
insert ParentList1;

List<Parent_Object2__c> ParentList2 = new List<Parent_Object2__c>();
ParentList2.add(new Parent_Object2__c(Parent2_Field__c = 'RandomParentValue'));
insert ParentList2; 

childList.add(new Child_Object__c(Parent_Object1__c = ParentList1[0].Id,
Parent_Object2__c = ParentList2[0].Id,
Child_Field__c = 'RandomChildValue'));
```

but the problem is that i am not able to access a Field value from Parent record without querying the inserted records (Please see screenshots below)

[image: WithoutQuery]

[image: PrintValueWithoutQuery]

With Query

[image: WithQuery]

[image: PrintValueWithQuery]

Is this is how it should be done or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way Salesforce SOQL works and you are not missing anything here.

From the child object you can access *other than* ParentId like as above.

To access parent's attribute, you need to execute the separate SOQL and specify all related parent attributes in the child's SOQL query.